# @html.DisplayFor() does not show the value from db table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This code in my View:
         @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.IsFree)

My Controller:
    Bool IsFree{get; set;}

My problem that:
IsFree: Checkbox flag, ceck and uncheck
I found that JavaScript that reset checkbox stat.

Comment: you are not even filling the property in your controller?!

Comment: This property read value from db table!

Comment: Possibly this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvcs-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value/

Comment: When i use @Html.TextBoxFor() i got the right value true / false? it's not value reading error it's somethings with the DisplayFor???

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` ?

Comment: Yes, but same problem!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.IsFree, new { @class = "checkbox" }
```